# How to redirect after celery work done on python Flask (not Django!)

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

My intentional full code is a website get and convert to mp3 from youtube video, save it to S3, then return the S3 link to the user.

Because I wanna use on low performance EC2 (save money) and also don't block many people use it on the same time so I used celery to do asynchronously.

After the celery done the work, I could execute callback function. But it's only shown on terminal, how can I (show it to replace) redirect the waiting screen ?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from celery import Celery
import youtube_dl

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://:password@redis-YYYY.cloud.redislabs.com:YYYY/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://:password@redis-YYYY.cloud.redislabs.com:YYYY/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


def done_download_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
    'progress_hooks': [done_download_hook],
}


@celery.task(bind=True)
def download_task(self, link, ydl_opts):
    # some long running task here
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([link])
    # and copy converted file to S3, return/get S3 link
    # I could handle the process from EC2 to S3.

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('hello.html')

# I try some decorators @app.XXXXX but no success.
def test_callback():
    print('it worked and run until here')
    # should redirect user to S3 link, or redirect the page with link to click
    # How can I do that ?
    return 'http://...'


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    download_link = request.form['text']
    # download_task.delay(download_link, ydl_opts)
    download_task.apply_async((download_link, ydl_opts),link=test_callback())
    return "please waiting, after done converting, we would redirect you to the link"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since celery runs tasks a separate process (or multiple, if you run multiple instance of celery), and you've chosen to make the experience asynchronous, to determine when a task is completed, a page on the browser is going to have to poll (i.e., via AJAX). That means it'll need some id that can be used to inquire about task status/results. The simplest id to use is the one handed back in the object you get when `.delay()`ing the task. Pass that along when you render the page so that it's available to make the AJAX call.

The view method to handle the call would then do something like

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult

@app.route('/taskstatus')
def taskstatus(uuid):
    result = AsyncResult(uuid)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'done': result.ready()}),
                        content_type='application/json')
```

When the page sees `done: true`, it can do whatever (redirect, change element's text or color, ...)

Comment: How are you getting the uuid here?